# When I upload a file to SkyDrive will it also be stored on my computer?

Tags: onedrive

I am trying to tidy up my computer so I would like to know:

If I store files in the SkyDrive folder will they be removed from my computer and only stored in the cloud or will they be stored on my computer as well?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Skydrive is a 2-way sync.

Comment: So I'm guessing it is stored on my computer as well.

Comment: A 2-way sync would indicate it would exist on the computer with the Skydrive client and in the cloud.

Answer (score 3):

Skydrive, like other cloud-based services (Dropbox, Google Drive, etc) is a 2-way sync meaning it will have files both in the cloud and on your devices.  So if you sync your desktop and your phone to use the same SkyDrive account, the same file will appear in all three (Desktop, phone, cloud) locations.  Changes to one will be copied to the other locations in time.

Finally, yes, if you sync with SkyDrive and then are offline, your files will remain available to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the SkyDrive desktop application, any files in you can see in your SkyDrive folders will be in both places.

This will change in Windows 8.1. 
http://blogs.windows.com/skydrive/b/skydrive/archive/2013/07/22/have-all-your-skydrive-files-with-you-without-using-all-your-storage-or-bandwidth.aspx